# React navigation 3.0 with the latest Expo SDK 40.0

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a react native application developed with [Expo](https://expo.io/). We recently decided to migrate from version 32 of SDK to the latest one. So, a lot of migration stuff had to be done but there's something we still struggle on. In general, we still struggle with the new Log box and the call stack it returns for a specific error:

```
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
```

The setup that we currently have is with the following versioning:

```
react: "16.13.1"
expo: "^40.0.0"
expo-cli: 4.1.6
react-navigation: "^3.0.9"
```

No we keep on getting errors that are a bit hard to determine what causes them because the call stack behind it is mainly related to files inside **node_modules**. So, for the following one I am wondering if I need to update the version of react-navigation (which would be a big change) to 4.x or 5.x in or not:

```
currentlyFocusedField is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use currentlyFocusedInput
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
- node_modules/expo/build/environment/react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/TextInput/TextInputState.js:39:4 in currentlyFocusedField
- node_modules/react-navigation/node_modules/@react-navigation/native/src/createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:46:63 in KeyboardAwareNavigator#_handleTransitionStart
* http://192.168.0.102:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:156311:56 in _callee3$
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:189:16 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:200:22 in doResolve
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:66:11 in Promise
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:188:15 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:211:38 in enqueue
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:238:8 in exports.async
- node_modules/react-navigation/node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/module/views/Transitioner.js:1:6360 in _callee3
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7106:2 in callCallback
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7127:20 in commitUpdateQueue
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15777:25 in commitLifeCycles
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18744:22 in commitLayoutEffects
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:265:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:476:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18483:29 in commitRootImpl
* [native code]:null in commitRootImpl
- node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18317:17 in commitRoot
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17697:12 in performSyncWorkOnRoot
* [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5321:31 in runWithPriority$argument_1
- node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5316:21 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5304:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17125:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7267:16 in classComponentUpdater.enqueueSetState
- node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:471:2 in Component.prototype.setState
* http://192.168.0.102:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:146243:26 in dispatch
- node_modules/react-navigation/node_modules/@react-navigation/core/lib/module/getChildNavigation.js:1:1477 in actionHelpers.actionName
- node_modules/moment/moment.js:5142:32 in <anonymous>
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:383:16 in callTimers
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

And when I manually navigate to:

> node_modules/react-navigation/node_modules/@react-navigation/native/src/createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:46:63

I can clearly see where the issue is but I am not sure how to fix it:

```
_handleTransitionStart = (transitionProps, prevTransitionProps) => {
      // TODO: We should not even have received the transition start event
      // in the case where the index did not change, I believe. We
      // should revisit this after 2.0 release.
      if (transitionProps.index !== prevTransitionProps.index) {
        const currentField = TextInput.State.currentlyFocusedField();
        if (currentField) {
          TextInput.State.blurTextInput(currentField);
        }
      }

      const onTransitionStart =
        this.props.onTransitionStart || navigatorConfig.onTransitionStart;
      onTransitionStart &&
        onTransitionStart(transitionProps, prevTransitionProps);
    };
  };
```

most probably it will work if I change **extInput.State.currentlyFocusedField** to **extInput.State.currentlyFocusedInput** but what is the point? I would get exactly the same after *npm install*

I can not really understand which parts of my source code causes that error, so I don't know which direction to go. The error message just pops up on the initial screen of our app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently ran into the same problem you described.

However, upgrading to version **4.x** is not as big a hassle as you might think.

Follow [this upgrade guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/upgrading-from-3.x) on the official website

The versions I used to get this working are:

```
"react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
"@react-navigation/core": "~3.7.9",
"@react-navigation/native": "~3.8.4",
"react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
```

Depending on the packages you used you might need to add a few more.